# How to marshal nested collections from POJO to XML in Jersey / JaxB?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I have two classes annotated as follows in Jersey v1.13:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="request_pojo")
public class RequestPojo {
    public String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "nested_pojos")
    @XmlElement(name = "nested_pojo")
    public List<NestedPojo> nestedPojo;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="nested_pojo")
public class NestedPojo {
    public String name;
}
```

When I attempt to use Jersey client to serialize a `RequestPojo` that has a collection of `NestedPojo`s ... I don't see them being marshalled in the logs:

```
INFO: 1 * Client out-bound request
23:30:45 web.1  | 1 > POST https://localhost:443/test/
23:30:45 web.1  | 1 > Content-Type: application/xml
23:30:45 web.1  | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
                  <request_pojo>
                    <name>blah</name>
                  </request_pojo>
```

What do I have to fix in order to see something like the following being put onto the wire by the jersey client?

```
<request_pojo>
  <name>blah</name>
  <nested_pojos>
    <nested_pojo>
      <name>nested blah</name>
    </nested_pojo>
  </nested_pojos>
</request_pojo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me your code works well.
Possible problems:
1) In your implementation of `List` iterator isn't implemented.
2) `nestedPojo` is empty or `null`. Debug project to check it